# Private key says passphrase is wrong when it is 100% correct

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, private-key

I am using a private key with the passPharse of `j` I have set this to test as its driving me crazy.

I am attempting to bitbucket, I have added the public key to their site.

I have added my `ppk` to `Pageant Key List` I had to enter the passphrase `j` when i add it to the key list so I am 100% confident that the passpharse is correct.

To test I am using `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`

```
$ ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/bitbucket2.ppk type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/bitbucket2.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/bitbucket2.ppk 
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/bitbucket2.ppk': //entered j
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/bitbucket2.ppk': //entered j
```

How can I clone things here.

Comment: Openssh doesn't use pageant as far as I know. You need to convert your ppk to an openssh private key (which puttygen should be able to do) and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ppk file is a proprietary key format for PuTTY; ssh doesn't understand this (and will likely just assume you entered the incorrect passphrase).

To resolve this, try the following:

1. Download PuTTYGen from the [official PuTTY downloads page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) if you don't already have it
2. Open it, then from the `Conversions` menu, select `Import key`
3. Browse to and select your .ppk file -- you'll note that you're prompted for your passphrase here (which in your test case would be "j"). Your key should be loaded into PuTTYGen now.
4. From the `Conversions` menu, select `Export OpenSSH key`
5. Enter any file name (based on your log, you could use "bitbucket2", with no extension -- if you want an extension, ".key" is a common extension for private keys) and click `Save`
6. Modify your SSH config (at `/c/Users/hUTBER/.ssh/config` based on your log) to reference the exported key instead of the .ppk file

Now when you use ssh, it should understand the key format. You will be prompted for your passphrase (that gets exported along with the key itself) and should be able to log in.